# Уточнение и расстановка запятых

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, верно ли я расставила запятые? 
"Все старые песни мне надоели, а из новых за последние полгода только одна заинтересовала". 
Или же "за последние полгода" тоже надо выделить запятыми? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Верно написано, верно отвечено.

А объяснить можно так: обстоятельство входит в основное сообщение (по структуре и интонации) и уточняющего значения при отсутствии обособления не имеет.

В принципе обособление возможно, но только при особом желании подчеркнуть и выделить паузами "за последние полгода".

Comment: Спасибо, что разъяснили!

Answer (score 1):

Да, Вы верно расставили. Выделять "за последние полгода" не надо.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: _____Не за что)